# "Goals of my diploma thesis" or "Goals in my diploma thesis"

Tags: prepositions

I am preparing my master's thesis defense slides, and I would like to have one slide in which just the goals of my thesis are written. Thus I would like to ask you which option of the following two is the correct one to write as title in such slide

> Goals **of** my diploma thesis

or

> Goals **in** my diploma thesis

I am also open to new ideas since I have no idea about what to write as title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question will probably get closed because it is about style, and style is primarily a matter of opinion. Nevertheless, I think it a good question about style.

First and foremost, I strongly prefer **Goals of** to **Goals in**. There may be many small goals within the body of the thesis that are preliminary to establishing the overall objectives of the thesis. **Goals of** makes clear that you are not listing everything in the thesis, but are discussing its overall significance.

Second, it is a master's thesis, not a this is for some other type of diploma. Because one writes a dissertation for a doctorate, you could perhaps just write **thesis**. In any case, it is unnecessary. I doubt anyone viewing the slide is expecting a short story or light verse.

Third, I personally hate **Goals** in this context. You may have had as a goal a proof of Goldbach's Conjecture, but if you failed to give such a proof, of what relevance is your frustrated hope? What people want to know is what you have established in your thesis. They are interested in your conclusions, not your aspirations. So I might go with something like

**Primary Conclusions**.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Jeff :) However I didn't get what you said about the diploma and master's thesis. Should you skip the word "diploma"?

Comment: I would not use **diploma thesis** for several reasons. As a matter of personal style, I avoid modifying a noun by a noun whenever I can do so gracefully. Furthermore, writing a thesis may be a requirement in some programs for earning a diploma that is not for a master's degree. So, to avoid any ambiguity, just write **master's thesis.** But everyone who will see your presentation will know that it involves a master's thesis. Saying so is not needed. Saying **My topic is A, and my primary conclusions are ...** and nothing more is strongest rhetorically because it explains where you are going.

Comment: I don't want to get mixed up in the debate, but, if you really wanted to use the words _goals_ and _thesis_, a concise title would simply be "Thesis Goals". Prepositions are often trimmed out of titles.

Comment: @JR I shall not debate style: it is too personal. **Thesis Goals** works as a title. It is not the one I would use, but it is not my presentation. What is good about your suggestion is that it retains the OP's own words.